# passing std::shared_ptr<<std::vector<double>> to a function

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to understand the use of shared_ptrs.  The simple code below

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<memory>

void funct(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double>> H){
    H->push_back(1.00); 
}

int main()
{
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double>> H;
funct(H);
return 0;
}
```

gives me a segmentation fault which I can't seem to understand. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to initialize the `std::shared_ptr`. By default, it is a `nullptr`. So you need to do `H = std::make_shared<std::vector<double>>()`. You can combine the declaration and initialization like so: `auto H = std::make_shared<std::vector<double>>()`

Comment: [OT] As you don't transfer ownership, better would be to use `void funct(std::vector<double>& H)`, and `funct(*H);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`H` is initialized with a null pointer, so dereferencing it causes undefined behaviour.

You perhaps meant to do this:

```
auto H = std::make_shared<std::vector<double>>();
```

This would create a new empty `std::vector<double>` object owned by `H`. A pointer to an empty vector is quite different from a null pointer (which points to no vector at all).

Comment: I see, the key is proper initialization of shared_ptr.

Answer (score 1):

Your smart pointer `H` is *default created*.
When a smart pointer is default created, its pointer value is a `nullptr`.

So when you dereference it (`*H` or `H->`), you will cause *Undefined Behaviour*.

In order to create a valid shared pointer, you can use the  [`std::make_shared()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) function.

For example:

```
int main() {
  auto H = std::make_shared<std::vector<double>>();
  // Now H is not a nullptr pointer.
  funct(H);
  return 0;
}
```

**(OT)**
*Simple Advise*
Passing a `shared_ptr` by reference is probably not a good idea!

Comment: You are right, the reference is not needed here at all!

Answer (score 1):

A shared pointer (or any smart pointer) behaves like a regular pointer in the sense that it is initially a nullptr, and after initialization will it start pointing at a specific memory address. In the case of a shared_ptr the initalization is best done with the make_shared function, which is described nicely in the reference if you need it.